# Migrate <procedure> from ibatis to mybatis

Tags: eclipse, mapping, mybatis, ibatis

When i use ibatis2mybatis to migrate this sqlMap

```
<procedure id="correctPcsInvoiceInCn"
    parameterClass="java.util.Map" >
    exec correctPcsInvoice 
        <isNotNull             property="insertingPersonId"       >#insertingPersonId#        </isNotNull>       <isNull             property="insertingPersonId"       > null </isNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="contractServicePerfID"   >#contractServicePerfID#    </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="contractServicePerfID"   > null </isNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="chemotherapyInvoiceID"   >#chemotherapyInvoiceID#    </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="chemotherapyInvoiceID"   > null </isNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="tariff"                  >#tariff#                   </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="tariff"                  > null </isNull>

        <isNotNull prepend="," property="medicalProductDetailsID" >#medicalProductDetailsID#  </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="medicalProductDetailsID" > null </isNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="drugPackageUnitsCount"   >#drugPackageUnitsCount#    </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="drugPackageUnitsCount"   > null </isNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="drugPackagePrice"        >#drugPackagePrice#         </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="drugPackagePrice"        > null </isNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="invoiceNumber"           >#invoiceNumber#            </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="invoiceNumber"           > null </isNull>

        <isNotNull prepend="," property="positionInInvoice"       >#positionInInvoice#        </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="positionInInvoice"       > null </isNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="taxPayerID"              >#taxPayerID#               </isNotNull>       <isNull prepend="," property="taxPayerID"              > null </isNull>
</procedure>
```

i get

```
<update id="correctPcsInvoiceInCn" parameterType="java.util.Map" statementType="CALLABLE">

    exec correctPcsInvoice 
        <if test="insertingPersonId != null">#{insertingPersonId}        </if>       <if test="insertingPersonId == null"> null </if>
        <if test="contractServicePerfID != null">,#{contractServicePerfID}    </if>       <if test="contractServicePerfID == null">, null </if>
        <if test="chemotherapyInvoiceID != null">,#{chemotherapyInvoiceID}    </if>       <if test="chemotherapyInvoiceID == null">, null </if>

        <if test="tariff != null">,#{tariff}                   </if>       <if test="tariff == null">, null </if>
        <if test="medicalProductDetailsID != null">,#{medicalProductDetailsID}  </if>       <if test="medicalProductDetailsID == null">, null </if>
        <if test="drugPackageUnitsCount != null">,#{drugPackageUnitsCount}    </if>       <if test="drugPackageUnitsCount == null">, null </if>
        <if test="drugPackagePrice != null">,#{drugPackagePrice}         </if>       <if test="drugPackagePrice == null">, null </if>

        <if test="invoiceNumber != null">,#{invoiceNumber}            </if>       <if test="invoiceNumber == null">, null </if>
        <if test="positionInInvoice != null">,#{positionInInvoice}        </if>       <if test="positionInInvoice == null">, null </if>


        <if test="taxPayerID != null">,#{taxPayerID}               </if>       <if test="taxPayerID == null">, null </if>
</update>
```

ibatis2mybatis generate this but i don't know is it good or not? Can any1 validate this part of code? And if possible change to good one.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use bean instead of map in myBatis

```
public InvoiceBean {
  private Integer insertingPersonId;
...
  //getters, setters
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<update id="correctPcsInvoiceInCn" parameterType="your.packadge.InvoiceBean" statementType="CALLABLE">

    exec correctPcsInvoice #{insertingPersonId, jdbcType=NUMERIC}, ...other parameters

</update>
```

adding jdbcType to parameter allows myBatis to set correct null value for it.